# PowerPoint.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(path) - On passing svg file path on existing shape, it is resulting in .png file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

On passing svg image to existing shape in Powerpoint 365 using PowerPoint.Shape.Fill.UserPicture(path) , the added image gets converted to png format. Any idea on how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: At this time, Powerpoint [does not seem to support](https://qr.ae/pNjyeF) importing SVG images.

Comment: Peter, this is true of older versions of PPT, but Geetesh's page that you linked to has been updated. @Moham I just answered this in MS Answers, where you also posted the question. Short version: it won't likely be fixed because it's not broken. PPT includes both the original SVG and also a PNG version of it in order to maintain compatibility with earlier versions of PPT that don't support SVG.